# Finding mount points with the find command?

Tags: mount, find

Is there a way to recursively search a tree for mount points on Linux? I'm looking to do something like this:

```
find /tree -type mountpoint | sort -r | xargs umount
```

Comment: Why not use the output of "mount" itself ?

Comment: I want to do a recursive, depth first unmount.

Comment: What about unmounting the longest path first, then the shorter paths?

Comment: I'm building chroots for a linux distribution and I"m often `--rbind`ing /sys, which has more than a couple sub mount points. It's annoying as hell to do by hand. I wish that umount had a depth-first recursive option.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay please edit that into your question. I was half-way into writing an answer based on mount before I noticed the comment. You need to include all your requirements in the question body.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `mountpoint` command and it supports `-q`, you could do:

```
find /tree -depth ! -type l -exec mountpoint -q {} \; -print
```

But that means running one `mountpoint` command per non-symlink file.

Note that at least the Linux `mountpoint` can get it wrong when a filesystem is masking a mountpoint. For instance, if one fs is mounted on `/a/b`, but then a different fs is mounted on `/a` later and also happens to contain a `b` directory, then `mountpoint` will claim `/a/b` is a mountpoint even though it's not. (that would rarely happen in real life though).

You'd probably be better off comparing each path with mount points listed in `/proc/mounts` (if on Linux) or the output of `mount`.

Like:

```
eval "$(
  < /proc/mounts perl -MString::ShellQuote -lane '
    BEGIN{@trees = @ARGV; undef @ARGV}

    $_ = $F[1]; # mountpoint is on the 2nd field
    s/\\(...)/chr oct $1/ge; # unescape \ooo sequences
    s/[[\\?*]/\\$&/gs;       # escape wildcards
    push @mountpoints, $_;

    END {
      # output the find command to evaluate:
      print shell_quote(
        "find", @trees, qw{-depth ! -type l ( -path},
          shift @mountpoints,
          (map {("-o", "-path", $_)} @mountpoints),
          ")", "-print")
    }' /tree /other/tree
)"
```

(`/tree` and `/other/tree` have to be absolute paths and symlink-free. That suffers from the same problem as `mountpoint`'s mentioned above).

If all you want is to unmount the file systems under `/tree`, note that the entries in `/proc/mounts` appear in the order they've been mounted, so to unmount them, just process that file in reverse:

For instance to unmount all the FS under `/tree`:

```
< /proc/mounts perl -l0 -ane '
    $_ = $F[1];
    s/\\(...)/chr oct $1/ge; # unescape \ooo sequences
    unshift @mountpoints, $_ if "$_/" =~ m{^/tree/};
    END {print for @mountpoints}' | xargs -r0 umount
```

If you know mount points don't contain newline characters, you can also do:

```
findmnt -rnRo target /tree | tac | xargs -rd '\n' umount
```

Or more verbosely/legibly:

```
findmnt --raw --noheadings --submounts --output=target /tree |
 tac | xargs --no-run-if-empty --delimiter='\n' umount
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not particularly elegant but it should work. Just ignore the errors and keep trying until everything is unmounted:

```
while mount | grep -q /tree; do 
    mount | awk '/tree/{print $3}' | xargs sudo umount 2>/dev/null
done
```

The above assumes you are a reasonable person who doesn't use whitespace or other strange characters in his mountpoints. If that's not the case, use this instead (this one assumes you don't have mountpoints with names that include both `on` and `type`):

```
while mount | grep -q /tree; do 
 mount | sed -nE 's/.*\s+on\s+(.*baba.*)\s+type.*/\1/p' | 
    xargs sudo umount 2>/dev/null
done
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "mountpoint" command to achieve this. For eg:

```
find /tree -exec sh -c "mountpoint {} 2>/dev/null" \; | grep "is a mountpoint" | awk '{print $1}'|sort -r | xargs umount {}
```

Comment: Embedding `{}` inside sh code is dangerous and bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

Try this ...

```
find /tree -depth -type d -inum 2 -print | xargs umount
```

Sorry, I am unable to test this ... but the theory is that the root of each filesystem will have inode number 2 (at least for ext[2-4] and most other unix-like filesystems ... to confirm this for `/` run `ls -ldi /` - the inode number will be the number in the left column).

Comment: What about bind-mounts, tmpfs, fuse, /proc, /sys? Note that non-directories can also be mount points.

Comment: Hence the note about unix-like filesystems ... but I'm interested in the "non-directories" comment. What "non-directories" can be mount points? (I'm not saying your wrong, I just can't think what)

Comment: On Linux, you can bind-mount any file except symlinks. (try `touch /tmp/test; mount --bind /etc/issue /tmp/test`). That allows simili-hardlinks across file systems.